# Autostart android code from flavor without override Application.onCreate

Tags: android

Recently I started develop new android appication. I decided to do a God mode or a developer mode to do a logs or forced to show some functionallity of app. This mode is only available for specific flavor or maybe be a separater android module (library), because I dont want to affect production code. My question is a possible to fires code from that mode (for example show notification) when app started without affect production code? For example not override Application.onCreate to start god module, beacuse in release variant i don't have access to code. If not I have a plan to check using reflection that specyfies class is in the classpath and if is run it, is good concept ?

Comment: if( BuildConfig.FLAVOR == "free" ){} this?

Comment: Nope, when I build release mode I don;t have access to code from god module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution I posted it to prevent asking questions. I use ContentProvider, because this component can start before Application.onCreate()

I found a solution I posted it to prevent asking questions. I use ContentProvider, because this component can start before Application.onCreate() was invoked, example code:

```
 /**
 * Content providers are loaded before the application class is created. [DevTool] is
 * used to install tools on application start.
 */
internal sealed class AppInstaller : ContentProvider() {

  override fun onCreate(): Boolean {
    val application = context!!.applicationContext as Application
    DevTools.install(application)
    return true
  }

  override fun query(
    uri: Uri,
    strings: Array<String>?,
    s: String?,
    strings1: Array<String>?,
    s1: String?
  ): Cursor? {
    return null
  }

  override fun getType(uri: Uri): String? {
    return null
  }

  override fun insert(
    uri: Uri,
    contentValues: ContentValues?
  ): Uri? {
    return null
  }

  override fun delete(
    uri: Uri,
    s: String?,
    strings: Array<String>?
  ): Int {
    return 0
  }

  override fun update(
    uri: Uri,
    contentValues: ContentValues?,
    s: String?,
    strings: Array<String>?
  ): Int {
    return 0
  }
}
```

And now i added to gradle

```
debugImplemetation devtool
```

and i Have debug tools in only debug build that now affect production code !